# MSBuild and Windows internals

Tags: windows, msbuild

Recently I needed to do some more advanced tweaking in our MSBuild/VS2008-based build system. My background is mostly UNIX systems, so I lacked knowledge on Windows-specific things; f.e. one of the surprises for me were that there are several different runtimes, which seem to be incompatible when linking two native projects compiled with different runtime libraries. I don't even know what to look for, so any help with making this question more precise is welcome ;-)

Are there any good books that explain these topics, together with some best practices?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which runtimes have you tried?

Comment: Well, this was only an example of a something surprising for me; it was the /MT, /MD, /MTd and /MDd options. I don't need help anymore on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best book on Windows programming: [Windows Via C++](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=11241&locale=en-us).

And anything else from Jeff Richter.

Important Caveat: I just noticed that *Windows via C++* is missing two very important chapters from the previous (4th) edition. I highly recommend you somehow get *[Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572319968)* just for Part VI: Windowing.

Comment: Looks nice. When I receive this book and check it, I'll make this answer as accepted.

Comment: `Windows Via C++` seems very verbose and I feel it is not getting into enough details. Main thing is that the book is thicker than necessary because of long code examples. Still noone suggested any other book... I'm not interested in UI, so I'm not going to check that second Richter book. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to take a look in Project Properties -> Linker -> System -> Subsystem. Take a look at [description of the property in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx).

Actually, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) with Bing is usualy the main source of any windows information along with books of Microsoft press, like man pages in UNIX

Comment: I'd like to be better prepared next time, and not to stumble upon such gotchas while doing the task. MSDN and searching the net is good when you look for some specific problems, and not to learn systematically.

Comment: You're looking for a specific problem, considering the runtimes. 
There are the following:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx (more specific),
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx (more specific),
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx (more common).

MSDN have articles for systematic learning, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381399%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't know MSDN also have tutorial-style documentation. Is there some kind of set of articles on this topic prepared for printing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've never printed it.